# How to PyOpengl or pyglet to draw on top of desktop?

Tags: python, windows, opengl, pyglet, pyopengl

I'm writing an application that is looking to draw basic polygons and ellipses on the Windows 7 desktop using OpenGL. According to this previous question, this is possibly by getting the window handle to the desktop, which I know how to do.
[Draw OpenGL on the windows desktop without a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935513/draw-opengl-on-the-windows-desktop-without-a-window)

However, I've got two questions:

1. Where do you actually tell OpenGL what window to draw to? I've been looking through nehe example 1, and I simply can't figure out where exactly it's passing openGL the hwnd. Do I give openGL a window handle or a device context?
2. Is it possible to do this using PyOpenGL or Pyglet? Or would I have to write it in C, then wrap the code in ctypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Trying to do OpenGL on another process' window is a really, really bad idea!** For OpenGL to work it needs to set the window's pixel format. However the pixel format of a window can be set only once, so doing this on a foreign window is a recipe for disaster.

The proper way to do this, but it's slow like nothing else is to use a PBuffer, which has it's own off screen HDC, render to this PBuffer and BitBlt from the PBuffer to the target window. I've never implemented this myself though, so I can't tell you how well this works first hand. But it sounds like an interesting thing to try, so maybe I'm doing that next time I boot Windows on my machine.

Comment: Thanks! When I think about it, this is really true. Come to think of it, this wouldn't have even done what I wanted, what I want is a window that's always on top with a transparent background.

Comment: @jmite: Then you should read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507 - layered windows don't work with OpenGL either, so the trick is again rendering in a PBuffer and BitBlt.